# Concatenating dictionary keys in python that may or may not exist

Tags: python, dictionary, string-concatenation, conditional-operator

I have a string that is parsed and segments are loaded into a dictionary. Depending on the string, certain keys may or may not exist. I then want to create a new string by concatenating specific keys from the dictionary. I'm having difficulty because some keys may not be present. I don't want a bunch of messy `if` statements so I am trying to use a ternary operator in my concatenation but it isn't working:

```
title = (name['title'], name['key1'] + (name['key2'] if name['key2'] else ''), name['key3'])
return ' '.join(title)
```

I get `KeyError: 'key3'` when the key doesn't exist. I presume because it is reading the key before it checks if it exists. I also tried:

`title = (name['title'], name['key1'] + (if name['key2']: name['key2']), name['key3'])`

but it wouldn't even run because of the syntax. I'm just trying to get the one key working for now but there will be more that will need to be concatenated conditionally so I'm trying to find a clean way to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the 'get' method? `name.get('keyX', '')` will return `''` if `keyX` is not a key. So your code becomes:

```py
title = (name['title'], name['key1'] + (name.get('key2', ''), name.get('key3', ''))
return ' '.join(title)
```

Comment: Extra parenthesis should be removed for the snippet to function as the OP intended.

Comment: Ah, that works well and is a bit cleaner than what I  was trying. I forgot about `get`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
title = [name.get(key, '') for key in needed_keys]
```

you can try this, just need to provide the list of keys

Answer (score 0):

You can test if key2 is in names.keys(), this way there is no error displayed

```
title = (name['title'], name['key1'] + (name['key2'] if 'key2' in name.keys() else ''), name['key3'])
```

Comment: This works good as well. I attempted something like this as well but I got the same error because I did `in names` instead of `in names.keys()`.